# How to convert the file with projections in meters to Lat-Long in QGIS ar Erdas Imagine?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have file in Lambert Conformal conic format for the data of Australia, Its coordinates are in meters. I want to convert it to Latitude-Longitude format. Which Projection, Spheroid and Datum I should be using if I want to convert the projections in QGIS or Erdas Imagine?

The current Specification of the file is as follow:
Projection: Lambert Conformal Conic 
Spheroid: GRS 1980
Datum: GDA94-ICSM
Map Units: Meters

Many Thanks in Advance for the Answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to permanently convert the data, export it to a new projection. If you just want it displayed with the Lat Long, select the CRS control down in the bottom right of the QGIS screen and change the CRS to WGS84.

Comment: How do you export the layer to a new projection?

Comment: Right click on the layer and SAVE AS. In that dialog, change from LAYER CRS to SELECTED CRS and then select EPSG:4326

Answer (score 2):

Your data is in EPSG: 3112, 3308 3107 or 3111. If you want lat/lon, best target CRS is WGS84 EPSG 4326. Thats the one GPS receivers are using.

If you are not sure about your data, install the openlayers plugin from Sourcepole Repository http://build.sourcepole.ch/qgis/plugins.xml (You have to add it manually), and let your data render on top of OpenStreetMap or Google Layer. You can change the layer CRS (not project CRS!)by rightclicking on your layer and watch the result.

If you have vector data, you can simply right-click on the layer and Save As..., giving the target CRS. If you have raster data, you have to transform with Raster->Projection->Transform, giving source and target CRS, and outut filename.

Answer (score 0):

Or... you could use ERDAS - Reproject, i find it better for rasters. Both of the coordinate systems ur dealing with are built in.

Comment: I am sure that this alternate method may be useful to the original poster.  It would be better, perhaps, if it were included as part of an answer that truly addressed the question being asked, regarding the appropriate Projection, Spheroid and Datum.  Having answers that are focused and relevant are equally as important to the quality of the site, as are having questions that are detailed and specific.